# my app crash when use socialSharing plugin in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i use ionic 3 and SocialSharing plugin it works well when using  :

> `socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp`

```
whats(){

    //this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("I needed a "+this.message,null,null)
this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("اI NEED "+this.message, null, null)
.then(() => console.log('ok'))
.catch(() => console.log('not ok'));


    }
```

but app crash and close in use :

> `shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver`

```
    whats(){
    //this.socialSharing.shareViaSMS("I needed a "+this.message,"+249922222343")
this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver("00249922222343", "I needed a "+this.message, null, null)
    .then(() => console.log('ok'))
.catch(() => console.log('not ok'));
```

}

ionic info :

$ ionic info

> cli packages: (C:\Users\abdo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
>       @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
>       ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1 global packages:
>       cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 local packages:
>       @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
>       Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
>       Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2 System:
>       Node : v8.9.3
>       npm  : 5.5.1
>       OS   : Windows 7

**Please help me**

Answer (score 0):

the country key must be there. 00 will not work, it must be + sign followed by the country key then the number i.e +310433885282. 00310433885282 won't work. Note that on Android you can only send a 'text' and 'url' directly to someone, so files are ignored.

**By phone number (since 5.3.0)**

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsAppToPhone('+31611111111', 'Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')})">msg via WhatsApp to phone number +31611111111</button>
```

**By abid (iOS) or phone number (Android)**

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver('101', 'Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')})">msg via WhatsApp for Addressbook ID 101</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the

```
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing-android12
```

plugin and you get the solution